# XE5 FireMonkey Android - Undeclared identifier alClient

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

I am currently developing a Delphi XE5 Android app and I am having trouble setting certain property values at run time.

For example a `TPanel` has a property `Align`, which can be set to `alClient`.

If I put a panel on the form I am able to change the property `Align` to `alClient`.

However if I try to set the property in code, the `alClient` has a squiggly red line under it and the error

> Undeclared identifier `alClient`

associated with it.

```
aPanel : TPanel;

aPanel.Align := alClient;
```

I think I have the right includes file, and have to have if the panel is on the form.

Any Ideas how I can fix this issue?

Comment: Figure it out. You have to use aPanel.Align := TAlignLayout.alClient;

Comment: Align is a scoped enumerator so you have to do what Shane and RezaRahmati have already pointed out.

Answer (score 3):

as it is an Enum you should use `TAlignLayout.alClient`